# Changing input of Edittext in Currency format

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Let's say i have input "22365.2588"  in my Edit Text.
I want to change it to USD 22,365.26 in my Edit text when i lose the focus of my Edit text. Using some specific java classes or i have to make my own?

How can i do that.Any hints and ideas will do
Best Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Focus Listner See this 
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/EditTextfocuseventlistener.htm
And 
You can do it Using java `NumberFormat`

```
  NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
            nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
            nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);


edittext.setText(String.valueOf(nf.format(Your value)));
```

More Clear....
 http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-number-format/#&slider1=1

Comment: how to do it on losing focus?

Comment: there is nothing written about changing focus in the link you have provided :S

Comment: EditText txt1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt1);
    txt1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {}

Comment: NVRMIND found it. Ty. setOnfocuslistener

Answer (score 0):

getCurrencyInstance() in NumberFormat:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance()